# Exchange 2013 not sending email via send connector

Tags: postfix, exchange, exchange-2013

I have Windows 2008 R2 with AD and Exchange 2013(10.0.2.2). And I'm using Postfix as SMTP for incoming/outgoing emails, which has two Ethernet interfaces - External IP and Local IP(10.0.2.25). I have added this SMTP as send connector for all the emails (*) and as receive connector for my domain. And this send connector is only one, set as Smart Host.

However when I send email from Outlook, nothing is happening. Postfix is not receiving from Exchange anything nothing is being logged out. Incoming emails are arriving through the same Postfix with no issues

```
Exchange2013(10.0.2.2) <== OK ==< (10.0.2.25) Postfix (Ext IP) <== Internet
Exchange2013(10.0.2.2) >== X?? ==> (10.0.2.25) Postfix
```

How do I debug Exchange in this case? I've seen on some forums someone mentioned about expired certificates on Exchange. Ping and telnet to `10.0.2.25 25` is all good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue is restarting the transport service

```
Restart-Service MSExchangeTransport
```

It took quite long to restart, but now emails arrive to Postfix

Answer (score 0):

So glad to know this issue is resolved. Sometimes, restart all services or server will solves many issues. You could mark the reply as answer.